# How do I do a Visual Studio publish with a TFS 2017 build server?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, web-config

I have a TFS 2017 server that I'm setting CI up on, however I'm having trouble getting the build definition to "publish" my project, my MSBuild step looks like this:

```
##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "FILEPATHTOMYSLN" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"SOMEPATHANDGUID\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=SOMEGUID|SolutionDir=RootofSolution"*ForwardingLogger,"SOMEPATHANDGUID\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="Debug" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="SOMEGUID"
```

How do I get MSBuild to create a publish build with only dlls and a transformed web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **Visual Studio Build** or **MSBuild** step, you just need to specify **Configuration** in the step and when building, it will transform the web.config according to the configuration you specify automatically.

For example, in the VS Build step, I use a build variable for the Configuration. Then I set the value of this variable to "release". When build runs, it will transform to the release version.

[image]
[image]

The MSBuild Arguments:`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

Comment: Yep, I thought I was doing most of that while trying to get it to work, I think my problem came down to inexperience with deploys and that I needed to look several directories into the obj folder to find what I needed in the packagetmp directory.  I did need to add /p:DeployOnBuild=true though.  The way it zips files doesn't work for AWS, so I added a few more build steps using 7zip instead.  This definitely set me on the right path, thanks!